# Whether $d_x(t) := \|P_t(x)-x\|_H$ is increasing in $t$ where $P_t:H \to H$ is the proximal operator of a convex function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space (e.g Euclidean $\mathbb R^n$), and fix a proper convex function $f:H \to (-\infty,+\infty]$. Given any $t \ge 0$, let $P_t:H \to H$ be the proximal operator of $f$ at level $t$, given by
$$
P_{t}(x) := \arg\min_{y \in H}\|x-y\|_H^2 + t f(y).
$$

Fix any $x \in H$, and define $d_x:\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ by $d_x(t):= \|P_{t}(x)-x\|_H^2$.

**Question.** Is it true that $d_x$ a non-decreasing function ?

**Example.** If, $f(x) := \|x\|_H^2/2$, then $P_{t}(x) \equiv x / (1+t)$, and so $d_x(t) = t^2\|x\|_H^2/(1+t)^2$, which is certainly non-decreasing in $t$.

Comment: plz. check lemma 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0258.pdf -- a similar proof should help here.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, in the Euclidean case $H=\mathbb R^n$, your Lemma 4 answer's my question in the affirmative (by taking $z=0$). The argument though written for the Euclidean case carries over to the Hilbert setting.